# How do I send a time to a MySql database with PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, time, timestamp

I am trying to send a time to my `MySql` database on `localhost` using a simple `PHP` query. Here's the code.

On the HTML side:

```
    <form action = "Timecard.php"
method = "get">
<fieldset>
    <label>Enter employee number:</label>
    <input type = "text"
    name = "EmployeeNumber" />

    <button type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "ClockIn">        
        Clock In
    </button>
    <button type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "ClockOut">
        Clock Out
    </button>
</fieldset>
</form>

And the PHP:
<?php
require ("conn.php");

$filled = true;

$EmpNum = $_REQUEST["EmployeeNumber"];

if ($EmpNum == "") {
    $filled = false;

}

if ($filled == false) {
    print "Must enter a valid employee number to log in. Click <a href = 'http://localhost/Employee Timecard/Timecard.html'>HERE</a> to return to the login screen";
} else {
    $timestamp = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
    $time = sprintf(date('h-i-s', $timestamp));
    print $timestamp . "<br>";

    print $EmpNum . " has just logged ";

    if (($SubmitButton = $_REQUEST["submit"]) == "ClockIn") {
        print "in on " . $date . " at " . $time;
        $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO timestamp(EmployeeNumber, Date, TimeIn, TimeOut) VALUES (".$EmpNum.",'".$date."','".$time."','')");
        print $query;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        print "checkpoint 2";
    } else if (($SubmittButton = $_REQUEST["submit"]) == "ClockOut") {
        print "out on " . $date . " at " . $time;
        $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO timestamp(EmployeeNumber, Date, TimeIn, TimeOut) VALUES (".$EmpNum.",'".$date."','',".$time.")");
        print $query;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        print "checkpoint 2";
    }
}
print "<br>checkpoint 3";
?>
```

When I submit to the database the date goes through fine but the time is incorrect -- something like `-00:00:47` or `00:00:05.` The type of the field in the database is set to `"time"`. Why would I be getting these results? It has to be simple, but it's driving me nuts.

Comment: The difference is processing time.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this. Can you elaborate? Rohan resolved the issue so the code works now but it's unclear to me why my code wasn't working properly. I suspect something in the way date() was formatted when assigned to the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use **date()** here,

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO timestamp(EmployeeNumber, Date, TimeIn, TimeOut) 
           VALUES (".$EmpNum.",'".$date."','','".date('H:i:s')."')";
 print $query;
```

Comment: Thanks, Rohan. Not sure why I was getting a syntax error when I put it into a variable first and using it that way.

Comment: No -- your original answer worked fine and resolved the issue. I'm just not sure why the date() function didn't work when it was used within the variable $time. Possibly because I copied it into the variable as a string by using the sprintf() function? It printed properly when I printed the confirmation string.